# Geodesic completeness of a Lie group

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, geodesic

Let $G$ be a Lie group and $\rho$ some left(right, bi)-invariant Riemannian metric on $G$. Is it possible to say for which $\rho$ an underlying manifold $G$ is geodesically complete (maybe for every such $\rho$)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For any $G$ and any left invariant metric $\rho$ on $G$, the underlying Riemannian manifold is complete. This is because $(G,\rho)$ is homogeneous (isometries acts transitively). See for instance this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31009/action-of-the-group-of-isometries-on-a-manifold) on MO.