# Is every semi-Riemannian group geodesically complete?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, semi-riemannian-geometry

I recently found out from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/975260/242708) that every Lie group equipped with a left-invariant Riemannian metric is a (geodesically) complete Riemannian manifold.

I wonder whether the same holds also for a semi-Riemannian group, i.e., a Lie group equipped with a *bi-invariant* semi-Riemannian metric. Any semisimple and any compact Lie group admits such a metric.

**Question**. Is every semi-Riemannian group geodesically complete?

If the answer is *no*, as I suspect, does it then change anything to assume that the group has dimension three?

Comment: Note that the argument in the linked post doesn't litterraly answer your question since a homogeneous pseudo-Riemannian manifold need not be complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To correct my earlier hasty comment:

Surprisingly (at least, to me), the answer is negative. Joe Wolf in Corollary 11.1 in

*Wolf, J. A.*, [**Isotropic manifolds of indefinite metric**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02566943), Comment. Math. Helv. 39, 21-64 (1964). [ZBL0125.39203](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0125.39203).

proves the following:

Let $G$ denote the unique (up to an isomorphism) noncommutative 2-dimensional simply-connected Lie group. (It is the Lie group of orientation-preserving affine transformations of ${\mathbb R}$.) Then $G$ admits an incomplete left-invariant flat metric of signature $(1,1)$.